# how to generate a new .desktop file (in /usr/share/applications) after installation?

Tags: xubuntu, wine, shortcuts, .desktop

I've just install wine in my Xubuntu 18.10 with the command "sudo apt install wine" but there's no shortcut in my menu.

I checked the /usr/share/applications, there's nothing there too.

Is there a way to generate that file. Try to uninstall/reinstall it with the softwares application or via synaptic but with no more success.

As I use Ubuntu/Xubuntu for 11 years, I found an alternative way to launch sketchup without anything in my menu but I think it should be fixed for the beginners.

Edit: The answer is not only to make a launcher. But the apt install program didn't create anything in the menu. I don't have neither the right clic option "open with wine..". I would like to have an integration of wine as usually in Xubuntu. It doesn't work for the 18..10 version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just copy one of the other desktop entries? I made this one and just called it phpstorm.desktop and it works:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PhpStorm\nComment=PhpStorm
Exec=/opt/PhpStorm-181.4445.72/bin/./phpstorm.sh
Icon=/opt/PhpStorm-181.4445.72/bin/phpstorm.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```