# Icon does not appear in the desktop files in /usr/share/applications

Tags: icons, executable

Im using  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Im trying to add some shortcuts to desktop. When I go to `/usr/share/applications` I see a lot of files, but none of them are with picture icons.
Where are all the executables for my apps?  I checked bin folder as well. Similar situation.
[image: Image of Applications folder content]

Comment: In Nautilus it is [not possible](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115). You have to enjoy Nautilus will all its great functionality and feature-reach. You can even press F3 to get extra pane (really not). So if you want to see icons -  install Caja instead of Nautilus or drop GNOMEs Hell and replace it with Cinnamon or MATE. [Here is how](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509).

Answer (score -1):

if the icon does not appear, try editing one of the files using your text editor. look for the Icon row section. point it to the location of your icon image file

```
Icon=/BASEPATH/YOUR/ICON/DIR
```

please correct if there is a shortage

Comment: Thank you. Tried that. Some of the files do not even have line with Icon="....".

Comment: Do the applications open when you click on the launchers in `/usr/share/applications`? I guess the icon not appearing is a bug in the file manager. They work for me in Xubuntu and Kubuntu.

Comment: You can add your own, it's flexible. some 3rd party files often forget icon files, maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Applications open with text editor and I see only  this for example: Desktop Entry]
Name=Handler for snap:// URIs
Comment=Prompt the user to install gnome-software then pass control to it
Exec=/usr/bin/snap handle-link %U
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/snap;
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application

Comment: yup, the file is correct, now you just enter one line Icon='...'.

```[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PhpStorm\nComment=PhpStorm
Exec=/opt/PhpStorm-181.4445.72/bin/./phpstorm.sh
Icon=/opt/PhpStorm-181.4445.72/bin/phpstorm.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true```

Comment: I think this can be used as a reference

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110258/how-to-generate-a-new-desktop-file-in-usr-share-applications-after-installat